# openmp, for loop parallelization and critical zone error

Tags: openmp

I am new to `OpenMP` and I am using it to implement the `Sieve of Eratosthenes`,  My code are:

```
int check_eratothenes(int *p, int pn, int n)
{
    int count = 0;
    bool* out = new bool[int(pow(pn, 2))];
    memset(out, 0, pow(pn, 2));
    #pragma omp parallel 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
    {
        int j = floor((pn + 1) / p[i]) * p[i];
        #pragma omp critical
        while (j <= pow(pn, 2))
        {
            out[j] = 1;
            j += p[i];
        }
    }
    #pragma omp parallel 
    for (int i = pn+1; i < pow(pn, 2); i ++)
    {
        #pragma omp critical
        if (out[i] == 0)
        {
            //cout << i << " ";
            count ++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

But, the above `OpenMP` pragma is wrong. It can be complied but when it runs, it takes a lot of time to get the result, so it press `CTRL + C` to stop. And I felt at a loss on how to solve it . Since there are many loops and if statements.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, It can be complied but when it runs, it takes a lot of time to get the result, so it press `CTRL + C` to stop.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, If I remove OpenMP pragma, it will produce right answer in 13 seconds. And I want to produce answer in about seconds.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, thank you sir, it can not produce the right answer.